# Display select options side by side

Tags: html, css

I would like to know if this is possible to change the normal display style of a select element in html

The normal `<select>` display style is like this :

```
[Select]
  | [option1]
  | [option2]
  | [option3]
```

Is it possible to display options like this (no dropdown, options side by side) :

```
[option1] [option2] [option3]
```

Comment: No, you will have to create your own component for this. This will just buttons for example, side by side.

Comment: @Tikkes, while the first part is correct, it is not really a job for buttons. semantically it is a list. You can attach an eventListener to it.

Comment: That would entirely depend on what the goal of the selection would be but I see your point.

Comment: @Tikkes I want to make search filter with it, and i don't know to do it clean

Comment: a good search filter would allow a multi-select not only one option. Either use checkboxes or a JS solution.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to change display property of default html select tag options. You have to either create custom select using JS or with external UI libraries like bootstrap.

Another workaround is to set `multiple` attribute.

Here is an example:

```css
select {
  text-align: center;
  background: yellow;
  display: block;
  white-space: normal;
}

option {
  width: 50px;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<select name="select" id="select" multiple size="3">
    <option value="1">option 1</option>
    <option value="2">option 2</option>
    <option value="3">option 3</option>
    <option value="4">option 4</option>
    <option value="5">option 5</option>
    <option value="6">option 6</option>
    <option value="7">option 7</option>
</select>
```

And then you can limit your multiple select with JS like so:

```
$("select").change(function () {
    if($("select option:selected").length > 1) {
        this.attr("disabled","disabled");
    } else {
        this.removeAttr('disabled');
    }
});
```